# DRUID SQL LATEST() and EARLIEST() returning zero

Tags: apache-superset, druid

I have this data source in druid:

[image]

I'm trying to use `LATEST()` to return the latest coordinates of each user active in the last minute. My intention is to show their location in realtime using a mapbox chart in superset. This is my query:

```
SELECT LATEST(latitude), LATEST(longitude), user_id FROM locations
WHERE __time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' minute
GROUP BY user_id
```

The problem is that `LATEST()` always return zero. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve what I want using DRUID SQL?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LATEST(expr)` returns the latest value of `expr`, which must be numeric.

If your columns is not numeric, use `LATEST(expr, maxBytesPerString)`

**e.g:**

```
SELECT LATEST(latitude,16), LATEST(longitude,16), user_id FROM locations
WHERE __time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' minute
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Column was not numeric, so LATEST(latitude,16) is working fine, thanks!